# On a Proof that the Splitting Field of a Separable Polynomial is Galois

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, splitting-field

**Prop.:** If $f \in F[x]$ is separable, then the splitting field of $f$ over $F$ is a Galois extension of $F$.

**Proof:** By induction over $[E:F]$, where $E$ is the splitting field.

By previous results concerning finite extensions, we know it suffices to show that $[E:F] = |\text{Aut}(E/F)|$.

If $[E:F]=1$ there is nothing to do.

If $[E:F]>1$, then we can write $f=pq$ where $p,q \in F[x]$, $p$ irreducible and $\deg p>1$. Since $f$ is separable, $p$ is separable. Write
$$
p(x) := \prod_{i=1}^n (X-\alpha_i),
$$
where $\alpha_i \in E$ are different. Let $E_i := F(\alpha_i)$. Then $E$ is the splitting field of $f/(x-\alpha_1) \in E_1[x]$. Since $m := [E:E_1]<[E:F]$, the induction hypothesis tells us there are $m$ elements in $\text{Aut}(E/E_1)$, let's say $\text{Aut}(E/E_1) = \{\tau_1, \ldots, \tau_m\}$. There are also $n$ isomorphisms
\begin{align}
\sigma_i : E_1 &\to E_i \\
\alpha_1 &\mapsto \alpha_i.
\end{align}
Each combination $(\tau_j, \sigma_i)$ gives an element in $\text{Aut}(E/F)$. Hence there are $mn$ elements in $\text{Aut}(E/F)$. But $mn=[E:E_1][E_1:F]=[E:F]$. $\blacksquare$

> **Questions:**
>
> 1. Does $\alpha_i \in E\backslash F$ for all $i$? In fact, this is used to deduce $[E:E_1]<[E:F]$? I think the answer to both is yes and that $\alpha_i \not\in F$ follows from the irreducibility of $p$ over $F$ and from the fact that $e \in E\backslash F$ & $f\in F$ $\implies$ $ef \in E\backslash F$.
> 2. To apply the induction hypothesis, we note that $E$ is the splitting field of $f/(x-\alpha_1) \in E_1[x]$. But is it not true that we have more simply that $E$ is the splitting field of $f \in E_1[x]$?
> 3. When we say that each combination $(\tau_j, \sigma_i)$ gives an element in $\text{Aut}(E/F)$, what are those elements? I think it must be some compositions, but the domains and codomains of $\tau_j$ and $\sigma_i$ don't quite match...? Also why are those $mn$ elements different?

Comment: Is $[E:F] = |\mathrm{Aut}(E/F)|$ your definition of a Galois extension? For finite separable extensions there are many equivalent definitions of being Galois.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva For me, $E/F$ is a Galois extension if $E^{\text{Aut}(E/F)} = F$. Then I have as a theorem : "If $E/F$ is finite then $E/F$ is a Galois extension iff $[E:F] = |\text{Aut}(E/F)|$".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Any root of $p$ cannot be contained in $F$, since otherwise you would have that $(x-\alpha) \mid p$ for some $\alpha \in F$, $p(\alpha) = 0$.
2. Think about what it means to solve this problem inductively. What we are doing is assuming that $[E:E_1] = |\operatorname{Aut}(E/E_1)|$. Why can we do that?
3. $\tau_j$ describes automorphisms of $E$ which leave $E_1$ fixed, and therefore fixes all conjugates of $a_1$ which is the set of all roots of $p$. $\sigma_i$ describes isomorphisms of $E_1$ onto $E_i$. We can extend $\sigma_i$ naturally onto an action of $E$, which does not affect elements orthogonal to $\operatorname{span}\{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\}$ (viewing $E$ as a vector space over $F$). Then $\tau_j$ and $\sigma_i$ commute as automorphisms of $E$. Furthermore, any automorphism of $E$ which leaves $F$ fixed can be described by its action on basis elements of $E$. I don't know of a simple way to justify this, but we can have a basis $B$ of $E$ which contains powers of $\alpha_1$ and elements orthogonal to $\alpha_1$. Then $\{\tau_j\}$ describes all possible actions of $B \setminus \{\alpha_1^k\}$ and $\{\sigma_i\}$ describes all possible actions on $\alpha_1$, so the set of compositions $\{\tau_j \sigma_i\}$ describes all automorphisms of $E$ fixing $F$, so we have that the number of automorphisms is equal to $[E:F]$.

Comment: Spent long time trying to understand, but failed :(. 1. I don't understand (IDU) your first sentence. Surely you mean $p$ instead of $f$ (we don't suppose $f$ is irreducible). I understand (IU) that $F(\alpha) \cong F(\beta)$ if $f$ is irreducible since both are $\cong F[x]/(f)$. So IU this shows that all $\alpha_i \not\in F$. IDU $F(\alpha) = F(\beta)$. The isomorphism I know between $F(\alpha)$ and $F(\beta)$ is $\alpha \mapsto \beta$. But it may happen $\alpha \neq \beta$. However we do have *an* isomorphism, so does it imply we can identify $\beta$ with $g(\alpha)$ **(cont.)**

Comment: for a certain $g\in F[x]$ s.t. $g(\alpha) \neq \alpha$? 2. I still think seeing $f \in E_1[x]$ should do it? All we want is a $f \in E_1[x]$ separable with $E$ as the splitting field? So why divide by $(x-\alpha_1)$ or even $p$ as you suggest? 3. Same question as in my comment about 1. concerning the *equality* of $F(\alpha_1)$ and $F(\alpha_i)$. IDU what you mean by *orthogonal* (there's no bilinear form defined on $E$). I think IU what you do if I take *elements orthogonal to* $E_1$ to mean *elements in* $E\backslash E_1$. I'll try to see how to obtain such a basis $B$.

Comment: I was mistaken; $F(\alpha_1) \neq F(\alpha_i)$ in general. I'll edit my answer soon.

Comment: Concerning your edit: 1. I don't see any contradiction with the fact that $f$ has a root in $F$. Indeed I don't see why $q$ can't have a root in $F$. 2. We're not assuming $[E:E_1] = |\text{Aut}(E/E_1)|$. That is what we get by applying the induction hypothesis which is that for any $F$ and any separable $f\in F[x]$, the splitting field of $f$ over $F$ is a Galois extension of $F$. We apply it with $F=E_1$. I still believe $E$ is the splitting field of $f \in E_1[x]$. 3. I think "$a_1$" should be "$\alpha_1$". *Orthogonal* still undefined. Anyway, thanks for the time you've put in..

Comment: If $F$ contains a root of $p$ then $p$ cannot be irreducible in $F[x]$. You *are* assuming that, otherwise why would you state it without proof? I feel that the author is trying to use the division by $(x-\alpha_1)$ to explain how induction is actually being used in this proof. I feel that it is not very straightforward; there is probably a much clearer way to explain it. I'm using 'orthogonal' in a very not rigorous way; it would be better to show that you can make a basis where every element is either contained in $E_1$ or fixed by $\tau_j$, although this is not trivial to show.